# How to Speed Up Conversion of CSV Dates to Pandas Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in CSV files with dates and times. I would like to convert these to Pandas Timestamps quickly, but the code below is taking too long. Is there any way to speed it up? The bottleneck step is the last one. Thanks!

```
TY1 = pd.read_csv('Data\TY_2013_1min.csv')
TY2 = pd.read_csv('Data\TY_2012_1min.csv')

TY = TY2.append(TY1, ignore_index=True)
TY.index = pd.to_datetime(TY.Date + ' ' + TY.Time)
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data of the datetimes? You can try `read_csv('Data\TY_2013_1min.csv', parse_dates=True)` or use `strptime` as your date formatter. It will be quicker (probably) to do this on the initial read rather than do it after reading the csv

Answer (score 0):

You can `parse_dates` directly while [reading the csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
TY1 = pd.read_csv('Data\TY_2013_1min.csv',
                  parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']],
                  index_col = 'Date_Time')
```

Note: perhaps it makes more sense to [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) rather than append:

```
TY = pd.concat([TY1, TY2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I've tried some of the suggestions on parsing the dates directly when reading the CSV file, but this doesn't help with the speed. E.g., the code you proposed takes 12 seconds for about 200k rows. This seems too long for so few rows.

Comment: @user3217037 Wow, it surprises me that it is so slow just to read_csv. How big is the csv? Can you post to it, or perhaps generate some fake data which is similar?

Answer (score 0):

they quickest way I found is to create your own parser.
For instance:

```
def dt_parse(s1, s2):
    dt = datetime.datetime(int(s1[6:]), int(s1[0:2]),  int(s1[3:5]),
                           int(s2[:2]), int(s2[3:5]), int(s2[6:8]))
    # depending on the datetime format you can move these values around
    return dt
```

And then you can specify in pd.read_csv what columns you are using for date and time (1 and 2 in this case) and what is your parser (dt_parse):

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path,
             sep=',',
             decimal='.',
             header=-1,
             parse_dates=[[1,2]],
             date_parser=dt_parse,
             index_col='1_2')
```

I found that for large files (~2G it makes it about 30% quicker) than to pull dates and times and separately create a list of timestamps. Hope this helps